# PHP ADODB AutoExecute Update Function for Adding Values to a Column

Tags: php, adodb

I am trying to add a view count for my comment system. I am using ADODB and I use AutoExecute for UPDATE and INSERT functions in my program.

I have to increase comment count by 1 when ever new comment is added.

So I use

```
$row['ccount'] += 1;
$con->AutoExecute("blogsys",$row,'UPDATE','id='.$id);
```

But this is not working and I tried with several possibilities to get succeeded with, but could not do it.